# ECMA6 function declaration style doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `parent` is a jQuery element, when I do this:

```
parent.change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).data('tab'));
});
```

This is working, but when I do this:

```
parent.change((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).data('tab'));
});
```

it's not working, why?

Comment: because `this` is different in arrow functions

Comment: Actually there's no function declarations in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword [get a different context within arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this).
Try this instead:

```
parent.change((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(e.target));
    console.log($(e.target).data('tab'));
});
```